# A recored for www

Tags: dns, cname

I set up an A record  for www

```
   Name              type              spec
WWW.MYSITE.COM         A            IP of the server.
```

Unfortunately somehow every visit to the site with WWW is redirect to the site without WWW

the default value of the record was:

```
   Name                type              spec
WWW.MYSITE.COM         CNAME            MYSITE.COM
```

as far as I know CNAME is redirect ,so and I change it to A recored.

72 hours had past and still no change !

What could be the problem?

How can I surf the site with WWW?do I have to change the recored to Cname again?

Thanks

Baaroz

Comment: CNAME is not redirect. It just says to DNS client, that IP address of www.mysite.com is the same as of mysite.com.
Redirect is most likely implemented in your webserver. If it's apache, look at .htaccess

Comment: no it's windows server 2008,any idea where to find it?

Comment: this might be URL Rewrite in IIS if it's installed

Answer (score 0):

if you specify www.mysite.com CNAME as mysite.com
than dns lookup result for www.mysite.com finds mysite.com as an alias and then resolves mysite.com with no www

So you should delete CNAME that you did true.

In linux system, you can use "host" command with "host -t a www.mysite.com ns1.nameserver.com (or localhost, if you are on that machine)"

Open your dns file manually. Your settings must be look like below. (after nameserver records of course)
and make sure that your CNAME record is deleted. There you can see your TTL (as seconds) and if it is bigger than we expected, this may be the problem too.

`domain.com.    14400 IN              A              1.2.3.4` 
`www.domain.com.    14400 IN           A             5.6.7.8`

Hope this helps.